# Process started with nohup is not detached from parent

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I have the following simplified scripts:

Python `test.py`:

```
import subprocess, os


def run_background_process(script_name):
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as FNULL:
        background_process = subprocess.Popen(['nohup', '{}'.format(script_name)], stdout=FNULL
                     , stderr=FNULL
                     , stdin=FNULL)

    return background_process

while True:
    run_background_process('test.sh')
    time.sleep(500)
```

Bash shell script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1

echo ${n}
sleep 30
```

And `ps -ef` result is:

```
15536 16555  0 14:18 test.py
15541 15536  0 14:18 test.sh
```

So my question is, why `test.sh` is not detached from `test.py` and it is still a child of `test.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every child process remains a child of its original parent unless the parent terminates. If that happens, the process with PID 1 becomes the new parent of the orphaned child.

Using `nohup` does not break that relationship. (To do so, the child must `fork` a new process and terminate itself, but that's another topic). So the first answer is yes, the child is still a child of its parent.

It is difficult to answer the other question directly. The meaning of "detached" in your question is not very well defined. I do recommend to check some tutorials about process groups (collection of processes), job control, controlling terminal and sessions (collections of process groups) in Unix/Linux.

The purpose of the `nohup` utility is to protect the started process from being terminated when you log out. The exiting shell performs a cleanup and sends the `SIGHUP` signal to all processes under its control. Further, the terminal device (keyboard input, screen output) in use will be closed during the logout. `nohup` just makes sure the `SIGHUP` is ignored and the terminal is not used. As a result, the corresponding process can continue its work after a logout.

Comment: My point is that I want the child to continue execution when parent is killed. This is not happening in the case above, if we put a forever loop in child it still terminates when parent is killed.

Comment: @CuriousGuy Could it be, that you are killing the parent with ctrl-C?

Comment: Yes, now I realize this is the problem... The child will live only if the parent exits normally, right?

Comment: @CuriousGuy The ctrl-C is sent to all processes in the process group, this includes the child. It is killed by the Ctrl-C.

Comment: Your comment really made me realize how processes work, I had totally wrong understanding.